# split column in multiple columns in sql view

Tags: sql

I have created a view for the Leco results and it is attached here as ‘Leco Teble’ excel file. I would like to have same view in database with ‘expanded table’ column based on the sample ID’s as given in the expanded table. Would you please arrange with one of your team member to create a script to expand the table in the same view. Last column in the table “Shift” should be picked up based on the time with the sample ID. 6am to 6pm is day shift.
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: As per question guideline, pls do not post images and tag your rdbms pls